# Gitlab Pipeline job failed angular build

Tags: angular, build, gitlab, gitlab-ci, production

When I buil project local build is success, but when gitlab pipeline build project is failed.

Error:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/office.service.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../models/bsResponse'.
```

when I run ng serve i haven't this error, and when I build project local

`image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind
stages:
    - build
    - deploy
variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
before_script:
    - apk update && apk add --no-cache bash
Build Docker image:
    stage: build
    before_script:
        - apk add --no-cache py-pip git
        - pip install docker-compose==1.23
        - echo -n $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    script:
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml push
    only:
        refs:
            - develop
Deploy to Portainer:
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - apk add --no-cache curl
    script:
        - curl -X POST $PORTAINER_WEBHOOK
    dependencies: []
    only:
        refs:
            - develop`

Comment: Can you add your current `.gitlab-ci.yml`, so it'll be easier to help?

Comment: added in question

Comment: It seems the error appeared due to `typescript` compile. Are you sure that ‍‍`bsResponse` file is in right location when `gitlab-ci` is running?